# Using MassTransit in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, autofac, masstransit

I currently have a WPF app that utilizes Autofac and MassTransit.  The main WPF window is a composite UI (a state section, commands section, and a main section) composed of different controls.  I communicate what is going on with these controls by using MassTransit and the InMemory transport.

As a user types into a particular text box I publish an "IRipWidthChanged" event.  The consumer for that event picks it up and does its thing in WPF just fine.

**View Model**

```cs
private string _ripWidthString;
public string RipWidthString {
    get => _ripWidthString;
    set => {
        if (_ripWidthString == value) return;
        FirePropertyChanged();
        FirePropertyChanged(nameof(ClearValuesButtonEnabled));
        _bus.PublishAsync(new RipWidthChanged.Builder() { NewRipWidth = value }.Build());
    }
}
```

**Consumer**

```cs
public task Consume(ConsumeContext<IRipWidthChanged> ctx) => Task.Run(() =>
    _viewModelFactory.Construct<ICommandsViewModel>().UpdateRipWidth(ctx.Message.NewRipWidth)
);
```

When the "RipWidthString" property's setter is called the bus publishes the message but my consumer is never called.  I've added faults and other mechanisms to see if something else is happening but nothing is getting called.

I'm also using the same code to setup my Autofac container between these front-ends so the view models and the ServiceBus is getting registered in Autofac.

***Edit 1***
Here is the code that registers the Autofac container

**MainActivity.cs in Android Xamarin project**

```cs
void RegisterDependencies() {
    App.Register<IMessageBox, AndroidMessageBox>();
    App.Register<IPopupMessage, AndroidPopupMessage>();
    App.Register<SemiAutoPage>();
    App.Register<CommandsControlViewModel>();
    App.BuildContainer();
}
```

**App.xaml.cs file in Xamarin core project**

```cs
private static void SetupDiContainer() {
    _builder.RegisterModule(new ViewModelModule());
    _builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceBusModule());
    _builder.RegisterModule(new FactoriesModule());
    _builder.RegisterModule(new ValidationModule());
    _builder.RegisterModule(new FileSystemModule());
    _builder.RegisterModule(new DataConversionModule());
    _builder.RegisterType<NullLoggingService>().As<ILoggingService>();
    _builder.RegisterType<MassTransitCommandExecutor>()
        .As<ICommandExecutionService>()
        .SingleInstance();
    _builder.Register(ctx => ServiceFactory.Construct<IPanelSawService>(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.12"), 5001))
        .As<IPanelSawService>();
    _builder.Register(ctx => ServiceFactory.Construct<IMachineStateService>(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.12"), 5001))
        .As<IMachineStateService>();
}
//...
public static void BuildContainer() {
    SetupDiContainer();
    _diContainer = _builder.Build();
}
```

And the code that sets up and registers the MassTransit bus

**ServiceBusModule.cs Autofac Module**

```cs
public class ServiceBusModule : Module {

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder) {
        builder.AddMassTransit(x => {
            x.AddConsumers(
                typeof(StateChangedConsumer),
                typeof(CutCompletedConsumer),
                typeof(SettingsConsumer),
                typeof(ExceptionConsumer)
            );
            x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(busConfig => {
                    busConfig.ReceiveEndpoint("panelsaw_queue", cfg => {
                        cfg.ConfigureConsumers(context);
                    });
                }));
            });

        builder.Register(ctx => new PanelSawServiceBus(ctx.Resolve<IBus>(), ctx.Resolve<IBusControl>()))
            .As<IServiceBus>()
            .SingleInstance();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me where the issue is -- are you saying that you are publishing the IRipWidthChanged message elsewhere in your application and that it's working fine, but here it's not?

It seems to me that there's a lot to unpack here and we may need more information: particularly the code that sets up your endpoints and bus. One problem I can see here is that you're not (and can't) await in a property setter. Try making the call synchronous (however you best do that in WPF), it's possible something is going wrong during publish?

Comment: In the WPF when the bus publishes the message my consumer gets called like I'd expect.  In the Xamarin app when the view model publishes the message my consumer is not getting called.  My View Models and consumers are shared between WPF and Xamarin projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anybody else who comes across this.  Just remember it is VERY important to make sure you start the service bus.  The difference between my WPF and Xamarin apps were that during the bootstrapping process the WPF app would resolve the IServiceBus interface and start it before the app would launch.

Once I did the same thing in the Xamarin app everything was working as I expected it to.  My consumers were being called with the correct information.